# TERADATA SQL: Populate one table through query results stored in another table

Tags: teradata

TERADATA SQL, I have SQL statements stored in a table. I want to populate another table with results of those SQL statements. SQL statements are different for each row and each column. Could you please tell me how I can achieve it? I have tried to get results through Stored Procedure and Shell Script. However, I couldn't code it properly.

Comment: You have select statements or insert statements in your table?

Comment: You have SQL statements stored in a table. In more than one column? Can you share the layout of this table and some sample data? I'm guessing a cursor to loop through this table and executing the statements dynamically would do the trick.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, I have SELECT statements in table. I want to run those sql queries and populate another table with query results.

Comment: @JNevill: SQL statements are stored only in one column of table. For example: Table with Query looks like this CustomerID CustomerName SQL Query
'101'  'Xi Houng' 'SELECT MAX(ORDR_AMT) AS MAX_ORDR_AMT FROM CUST_SALES WHERE ORDR_DT=''01-03-2017'' '
'102'  'Fran Lombard' 'SELECT MAX(PAY_DT) AS MAX_PAY_DT FROM CUST_TRANS WHERE ORDR_ID=''TS9821'' '
and Target Table looks like CustomerID CustomerName    SQL_RESULT   I don't have much experience in Teradata Stored Procedure. Please help me How I can achieve the result populated in target table. Suggest how I can solve this problem.

Comment: So the target table will take the CustomerID and CustomerName from the source table, and the last field `SQL_RESULT` will take the result from the SQL Statements stored in the source table? This means that the SQL statements held in the `SQL Query` field in your source table will only produce a single record with a single field, correct?

Comment: @JNevill: Yes, Result will be single value with single field. SQL statements will be static which i inserted manually.

Comment: I am facing this problem now. If a SQL statement returns no records means that record doesn't exist for that SELECT statement. Then, how to jump to the next SQL statement which returns any value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty barebones procedure for pulling something like this off. It gets a little hairy because:

1. We are employing a cursor to loop through your source table that holds the SQL Statements
2. We are employing a second cursor while looping through the first cursor to dynamically execute the SQL String and FETCH the results of that SQL query into a variable.

I would suspect you will run into all sorts of bugs while getting this set up, but I believe this is pretty close to a working procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <yourdatbase>.MyNewProcedure()
BEGIN
    --Declare variables to hold the three fields as we loop through them with the cursor
    --You'll need to change these types to match your table's data type so we can fetch
    --  them without error inside the cursor loop
    DECLARE customerID INT;
    DECLARE customerName VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE sqlQUERY as VARCHAR(10000);
    DECLARE source_table_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT customerID, customerName, SQLQuery FROM <yourdatabase>.yoursourcetable FOR READ ONLY;

    OPEN source_table_cursor;
        looplabel: 
        LOOP
            --We'll need a cursor for a dynamic statement
            --And we'll also need an integer to catch your query
            --results (Assuming they are all like (Sum(<somefield>) or some
            --type of INT
            DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR S1;
            DECLARE sqlResults as INT;

            FETCH source_table_cursor INTO customerID, customerName, sqlQuery;

            --WOAH THERE! Cursor issues something went wrong die die die
            IF (SQLSTATE ='02000') THEN
                LEAVE label1;
            END IF;     

            --Now that we have a record and a sql statement we will need another cursor
            --where we will execute, dynamically, the SQL statement and then fetch the
            --single record result to update our target table           
            PREPARE S1 FROM sqlQuery;
            OPEN C1;
                FETCH C1 INTO sqlResults;

                --Now we can INsert into your target table
                INSERT INTO <yourdatabase>.yourtargettable (customerID, customerName SQL_RESULT)
                     VALUES (customerID, customerName, sqlResults);

            CLOSE C1;

        END LOOP looplabel;
    CLOSE demographic_cursor;
END
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution.

Comment: I created stored procedure as you developed. I am unable to understand How SQL statements are running and getting results in sqlResults. I want to know how " PREPARE S1 FROM sqlQuery;"  is fetching results from queries.

Comment: `sqlQuery` is a varchar/string that is being populated with the SQL statement for the record in the first cursor (from your table). We created a cursor that is created from a Statement `S1`. `S1` is "prepared" from the sql statement in `sqlQuery`. Once that statement is "prepared" we can then open the `C1` cursor and populate it with the records from the `sqlQuery` string that perpared the `s1` statement. It's a lot of jumping through hoops in order to dynamically execute a sql statement stored in a column.

Comment: Some of rows in sqlQuery column are NULL. Then Cursor will not be able to fetch SQL results when it tries to execute it. I don't know what should be the logic in cursor which jump over to NULL sqlQuery column.

Comment: I would adjust the SQL query used to load `source_table_cursor` Cursor with a WHERE statement like `WHERE sqlQuery IS NOT NULL` to avoid those records from ever entering the cursor. Alternatively you could add an IF statement inside the cursor's loop to check (but that would be more expensive then the WHERE solution).

Comment: But I want each record to be inserted in Target table. When sqlQuery column is NULL in source table then I want SQL_Result as NULL in Target table. Here, Cursor is fetching each data except  WHERE sqlQuery IS NOT NULL. e.g. customerId, customerName, sqlQuery - 111, zzz, NULL then customerId,  customerName, SQL_Result - 111, zzz, NULL. Where clause is filtering sqlQuery Null data as well.

Comment: Ah!. How about... Instead of a WHERE we change that SQL statement to: `SELECT customerID, customerName, COALESCE(SQLQuery, 'SELECT NULL') as SQLQuery FROM <yourdatabase>.yoursourcetable`  That way in the event that it's null it will be replaced with a SELECT statement that will produce a NULL response from the database when submitted.

Comment: Yes, It is better. Now I get all results in target tables. Thanks

Comment: I am facing this problem now. If a SQL statement returns no records means that record doesn't exist for that SELECT statement. Then, how to jump to the next SQL statement which returns any value.

Comment: I think you'd want to look at that `sqlResults` variable. Like `if (sqlResults IS NOT NULL) Then ... go on and do the insert,

Comment: But it is not about NULL value, there is no data returned for specific SQL Statement. Then I will not even get NULL value. It is like if I run a query which doesn't return anything. No record is returned. So I am trying to find a way to skip that step in loop and go to net row.

Comment: Then what is being inserted when that condition occurs in that field? I suspect that variable is set to NULL when the query returns no results OR you are correct, but then the insert statement would never run and it would simply iterate to the next sql statement (next row).